# Value of ratio of inverse trigonometric values

Tags: trigonometry

> How to prove that the value of the following expression is $2$ manually?

Please tell me the quickest method to deal with such problems.

$$\frac{\cos^{-1}(\frac{41}{49})}{\sin^{−1}{(\frac{2}{7})}}$$

Comment: Both the numerator and the denominator may be interpreted as angles. If you draw the right-angled triangle for each of them, perhaps on top of eachother in some clever way, you can find a _geometric_ reason why one angle should be the double of the other.

Comment: Does $\cos^{-1}$ mean $\arccos$ or $\frac{1}{\cos}$?

Comment: @5xum I guess the latter would be a ridiculous way of asking the question :-P!Hehe...the former is the right interpretation :-)!

Comment: @Arthur waiting for your answer :).. i still could'nt do it...

Comment: @SanchayanDutta It was just an idea, I haven't actually solved it. Hence the "perhaps" wedged in there.

Comment: Oh I see....umm,btw do try it when you are free (if possible).Anyway thanks for the idea...i'm still trying it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that $\cos(2x) = 1-2\sin^2(x)$ (this time $\sin^2(x)$ means $(\sin(x))^2$). Letting $x$ be the the denominator of the fraction, we get that
$$
\cos(2x) = 1 - 2\sin^2(x) = 1-2\cdot\frac{2^2}{7^2} = 1-\frac8{49} = \frac{41}{49}
$$
which means that the angle in the numerator and $2x$ have the same cosine value. Therefore they must be the same (since everything here is between $0^\circ$ and $90^\circ$).

Answer (score 0):

$\sin^{-1}\dfrac27=y\implies\sin y=\dfrac27$

$$\dfrac{41}{49}=\cdots=\cos2y$$

Now $\cos^{-1}(\cos2y)=2y$ if $0\le2y\le\pi$